# Is there friction between liquids?

Tags: friction, liquid-state

Imagine you have two slightly different liquids, or a couple of underwater streams facing eachother. Can there be any friction between them? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is called viscosity.

Comment: Consider an object falling through air. Resistance from the air slows the object, by means of friction leading to drag. Consider the same object moving through a liquid. It will feel a similar frictional drag. Perhaps this idea can be extended for fluids of varying densities moving through a fluid medium (viscous resistance).

Comment: Maybe you got the question wrong. I'm asking about the surface friction between two liquids (or "rubbing" same liquid), not the thickness of the liquid which viscosity shows. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @bleuofblue that's exactly what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But we use a different name for it, **Viscosity**.

Comment: I believe it's not the same, the viscosity shows thickness of a liquid, I'm asking if there would be surface friction in between two liquids that are different or moving in opposing directions. Imagine a splash of acetone in water, or some heavier liquid sinking in water, is there any friction between them? Or am I getting it wrong? Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Fluid surfaces are also resists any relative motion. They have friction. We call this friction, __Viscosity__, or sometimes it is also called as _Fluid Friction_.

Comment: @Aras Assume laminar flow. Then the velocity profile is continuous over the interface, both sides of the interface have the same velocity. One can give the liquids a different color: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNUK-L-tEAw

Answer (score 0):

I think that friction and viscosity are slightly different, but I may be wrong. However, they are very closely linked. The friction of a fluid is also known as 'Fluid-friction'. The higher the viscosity of a liquid the higher the friction between the two.

There would be friction as the particles would bump and rub against each other from the different liquids however, the friction is relatively small and is often neglected in many calculations.

I may be wrong, but I hope this helps